# Creating xml file in proper format

Tags: python

I tried converting my csv file to xml but I am facing issue in assigning correct tags and their corresponding values xml.
This is how my xml file should look like as shown in img1[image]:

whereas how it is getting generated as shown in img2:
[image]

I have written the following code:

```
csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0"?>' + "\n")
# there must be only one top-level tag
xmlData.write('<MCD>' + "\n")

rowNum = 0
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', '_')
    else: 
        #xmlData.write('<' + )
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('    ' + '<' + row[i] + '>' \
                          + row[i] + '</' + row[i] + '>' + "\n")
        #xmlData.write('</row>' + "\n")
            
    rowNum +=1

xmlData.write('</MCD>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

My csv files looks as shown in img3:[image]